# jQuery - replace class + slide up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I'm trying to replicate some functionality on http://www.stationfour.com/Work

When you hover over the image, a div with an H2 and H3 slides up. It slides back down upon exit.

My site is using Bootstrap. The code I have is a bit different from theirs (no li tags) but that shouldn't be a problem.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <a href="http://avondaleriverside.com/all/mike/hash/hash.php" target="_blank">
    <img class="responsive" src="img/portfolios/hashing.png" alt="Hashing and Salting" width="" height="">
  </a>
  <div class="infoBox hidden" style="bottom: -50px; opacity: 0;">
    <h2>
      <a href="hash.php" target="_blank">Password Hashing &amp; Salting</a>
    </h2>
    <h3>
      Password Security
    </h3>
  </div><!-- / .infoBox -->
</div><!-- / .col-md-3 -->
```

And the jQuery

```
$(div).hover(function () {
  $(this).removeClass("hidden");
  $(this).slideToggle(250);
}, function() {
    $(this).addClass("hidden");
});
```

I imagine this should be simple, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, the lack of any jQuery code to handle the showing/hiding is the first issue! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jsBin accomplishing it with only CSS. Because javascript, and furthermore jQuery, is 100% not necessary to accomplish such a simple task like this.

[JsBin Link](http://jsbin.com/povazi/1/edit?html,css,output)

Here's the CSS:

```
.box {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box .info {
  width:100%;height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:-100px;
  opacity:0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.75);
  color: #fff;
  /* transition */
  transition: all 250ms linear;
}
.box:hover .info {
  bottom:0;
  opacity:1;
}
```